# html2canvas - pure svg renders fine but svg inside img tag has issues

Tags: css, svg, html2canvas

here is my code:

```
<svg width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icons-ca" viewBox="0 0 640 480"><path fill="#fff" d="M150.1 0h339.7v480H150z"/><path fill="#d52b1e"  d="M-19.7 0h169.8v480H-19.7zm509.5 0h169.8v480H489.9zM201 232l-13.3 4.4 61.4 54c4.7 13.7-1.6 17.8-5.6 25l66.6-8.4-1.6 67 13.9-.3-3.1-66.6 66.7 8c-4.1-8.7-7.8-13.3-4-27.2l61.3-51-10.7-4c-8.8-6.8 3.8-32.6 5.6-48.9 0 0-35.7 12.3-38 5.8l-9.2-17.5-32.6 35.8c-3.5.9-5-.5-5.9-3.5l15-74.8-23.8 13.4c-2 .9-4 .1-5.2-2.2l-23-46-23.6 47.8c-1.8 1.7-3.6 1.9-5 .7L264 130.8l13.7 74.1c-1.1 3-3.7 3.8-6.7 2.2l-31.2-35.3c-4 6.5-6.8 17.1-12.2 19.5-5.4 2.3-23.5-4.5-35.6-7 4.2 14.8 17 39.6 9 47.7z"/>
```

```
<img width="100" src="{{generate_src()}}lfc/graphics/more/flags-4x3/test.svg"/>
```

This is what it looks like in the browser:

[image: pure svg]

But when I print to an image using html2canvas the viewport for the img tag is acting weird - it looks like its only showing the top left of the flag. I have scale 2 but when I set it to 1 it doesn't help. Any help is appreciated.

[image: html2cnvas]

Here is the code to print the image

```
<script>
window.takeScreenShot<?= $rand ?> = function () {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("takeScreenShot<?= $rand ?>"), {
        scale: 2,
        dpi: 360,
        backgroundColor: null,
        width: document.getElementById('takeScreenShot<?= $rand ?>').offsetWidth,
        height: document.getElementById('takeScreenShot<?= $rand ?>').offsetHeight
    }).then(function (canvas) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
            a.download = 'fsf_<?= $rand ?>.png';
            a.click();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Here is the code to print the image

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by specifying the width and height in the svg tag:

```
<svg width="262" height="28" viewBox="0 0 262 28" fill="none" >
```